# Multisite wordpress and subdomain URL collisions

Tags: multisite, permalinks, url-rewriting, htaccess, subdomains

I have a multisite WordPress installed on a server using a domain, **site.com** and I have a subdomain setup in WordPress, so subsites are at **sub1.site.com**, **sub2.site.com** etc.

In addition to this, the main site has other services in subfolders that are not related to WordPress, such as `site.com/something`.

Everything is working fine, except that when a customer on a subsite uses permalinks by post name, and uses the same title as one of the main site's subfolders, it goes to the main site's subfolder; for example `sub1.site.com/something` goes to the same place as `site.com/something`.

Is there anything I can do *(by editing `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf`*?

Or should I just move WordPress to it's on subfolder in main site (`site.com/wordpress`) to prevent these URL collisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just prevent slugs matching existing directories. There are two filters for that.

Example, not tested:

```
add_filter( 
    'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_hierarchical_slug', 
    'prevent_directory_slugs', 
    10, 
    2 
);
add_filter( 
    'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_flat_slug', 
    'prevent_directory_slugs', 
    10, 
    2 
);

function prevent_directory_slugs( $bool, $slug )
{
    return is_dir( ABSPATH . '/' . $slug );
}
```

Comment: Hey that works. Thanks a lot. However, if anyone knows a solution that would actually allow using slugs with the same name as folders on main site, that would be even better.

Comment: @Kari how would you access both if the slugs and folder names are the same?